# ffprobe reading wrong frame rate, any workarounds besides MediaInfo?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, ffprobe, media-info

I want to check the frame rate of many videos to double it. I use `ffprobe` to get `r_frame_rate` which is evaluated to a decimal, then fed into `ffmpeg` as rscale `-r {2*fps}`, or into `mkvmerge` as `0:{2*fps}fps`.

And so, I start with:

`ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate faulty.mkv`

```
500/21
```

That can't be right, what kind of fps is 500/21? Turns out saving it with `500/21` desync with audio, which doesn't happen for `24000/1001`. This value is **definitely** wrong.

At least ffprobe 4 read the correct codec timescale i.e. `23.98 tbc (default)`:
`ffprobe faulty.mkv` (version 4.3.5-0+deb11u1+rpt3)

```
Stream #0:0: Video: (...), 23.81 fps, 23.81 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
```

but in later versions `tbc` has been deprecated:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: (...), 23.81 fps, 23.81 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
```

However, MediaInfo simply gets it right:

`mediainfo faulty.mkv` =

```
(...)
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
(...)
```

I tried using `-count_packets` to then divide `nb_read_packets` of the stream by the `duration` of the file, I'm getting 1 second per hour error. This is much better compared to 23,8095, but packets are not frames. Only the prohibitively, unusably slow `-count_frames` gets me the exact value.

My workflow *has* to use `ffprobe` one way or another, so I'm reluctant to always run `mediainfo` on top of that for performance reasons. I get that the file is, well, faulty, but if `mediainfo` can do it, is there a way to make sure the correct frame rate is read with `ffprobe` without decoding the entire file as `-count_frames` seems to do?